# Use python subprocess.call to run a .exe in another directory

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

I have run into a wall trying to use `subprocess.run()`.

In windows, outside Visual Sudio, I open a command window and get:

```
c:\users>
```

Then I change directory

```
c:\users>cd c:\xfoil
```

Then I run the xfoil program

```bash
c:\xfoil\xfoil.exe < input_file.txt
```

xfoil runs and generates output text files.

I am trying to get this embedded in my code so I don't have to manually generate and import the xfoil input/output text files.

Here is an example of code I tried that didn't work.

```py
import subprocess

xfoil_output = subprocess.run(r'c:\xfoil\xfoil.exe < input_file.txt')
```

It runs, but just runs forever, it doesn't give any errors, or create any output files. (Xfoil should generate those files in the xfoil directory, don't know or care what value the variable xfoil_output has). I have to stop debugging to end the program.

Found lots of examples here and elsewhere but can't make it work.

Comment: Please *format your code correctly*. this requires a modicum of effort.

Comment: I *suspect* the issue is that you are using `<`, which I assume requires a shell. I am not very familiar with windows though

Comment: Your working cmd based command shows that `xfoil.exe` is in ```C:\```, "`c:\xfoil.exe`". Your python code however appears to be instead running `c:\xfoil\xfoil.exe`! If that is a typo, then please be more careful when composing your question, and [Edit] it to make the correction.

Comment: Sorry about the formatting. I don't know how. You're right the command line for executing xfoil should be c:\xfoil\xfoil.exe < input_file.txt. Sorry for both transgressions.

Comment: Technically, in that situation, it could be `xfoil.exe < input_file.txt`. The current directory is already `C:\xfoil`, so there is no need to prepend the parent directory path to it.

Answer (score 0):

You should read the contents of the input file first, then should use subprocess.run() to execute XFOIL by providing the input content directly, like below:

```
import subprocess
import os

os.chdir(r'c:\xfoil')

with open(r'input_file.txt', 'rb') as f:
    input_content = f.read()

xfoil_process = subprocess.run(['xfoil.exe'], input=input_content, capture_output=True)
xfoil_output = xfoil_process.stdout
```

Comment: OK, AWESOME! That worked, it ran XFOIL. I had to put an "r" in front of the input file path. But the output file gives me an error. I tried commenting the line out because I am happy with the output (there are multiple output files generated by each input) but those files aren't showing up in the xfoil directory like I expected. Do I need to use CWD to change the active directory or something?

Comment: with open(r'c:\xfoil\naca4412_10_input.txt', 'rb') as f:
    input_content = f.read()

xfoil_process = subprocess.run(['c:\\xfoil\\xfoil.exe'], input=input_content)
output_text = xfoil_process.stdout.decode('utf-8') Sorry this comment tool is giving me fits.

Comment: I tried using an input file that only generated a single output file and still got this error         'NoneType' object has no attribute 'decode'

Comment: Pls, retry as like modified answer.

Comment: OK that made the error go away. xfoil_output has the xfoil output text dumped into it. If I ran this manually the xfoil output text file(s) would show up in the xfoil dir. Maybe they are going someplace else? I did a windows file search and couldn't find them. Regardless, since my data retrieval code is set up to get the data from the output files in the xfoil directory is there anyway to get the output files to generate in the xfoil dir (like if I ran xfoil manually). Maybe I just need to dump xfoil_output into a text file in any directory I want? Regardless thanks for you help.

Comment: and maybe I should take a Python class...

Comment: You can add an argument `cwd='someDirectory'` to your `subprocess.run()` to change directory before running it.

Comment: i modified answer by changing directory first then execute Or you can execute this code in where xfoil.exe placed.

Comment: **xfoil_process = subprocess.run(['c:\\xfoil\\xfoil.exe'], input=input_content, capture_output=True)**  Where would I put **cwd='c:\xfoil'** in the subprocess.run. And sorry, I can't figure out how to format comments.

Comment: I know how to comment in Python, but not in these forum comments. I'm learning... **AND THANKS AGAIN**

Comment: **OK that fixed everything! Thanks so much.** I've been working on this code for more than a year and this is the 1st time I couldn't figure something out, or at least make it work. Lots I don't really understand...

Comment: Put code inside backticks to format as code in comments. Inside asterisks to make italic. Inside double asterisks to make bold. Inside triple asterisks to make bold and italic.